# Fields of Study Introduced by Leonhard Euler

Tags: mathematics, physics, mathematicians

Leonhard Euler is called the *Father of Graph Theory*. He also started off the studies of *Calculus of Variations*.

Which all are the other mathematical/science disciplines that evolved as an independent field of study because of him?

Quick Google search did not return any good documents on it, the closest I could find is this [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Leonhard_Euler#Notes) and [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributions_of_Leonhard_Euler_to_mathematics), but both of them doesn't explicitly mention disciplines that were started off by him, far as I read.

(Also [asked in Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2350449/45937), moved it here since it was suggested that it's more appropriate to hsm.SE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many areas of science in which Euler can be called a founding father, though in most cases some predecessors can be found:

In mathematics and mechanics: Calculus of variations (Newton and Bernoulli were predecessors), fluid dynamics (again Newton and Bernoulli can be counted as predecessors), rotation of a rigid body, elliptic integrals, use of generating functions in number theory, the theory of partitions, elasticity theory, complex function theory. He also discovered Gamma, Beta, zeta and hypergeometric functions, 
and possibly Bessel functions, which qualifies him as the father of the Special function theory. (I do not even mention that he discovered the exponential function of a complex argument too). Euler is also a founding father of  holomorphic dynamics which is very fashionable nowadays: he was the first to
study systematically the iteration of the exponential functions (though here too he had a predecessor, marquis de Condorcet). 90% of the modern undergraduate course of Ordinary Differential Equations is also due to Euler.

In physics and engineering: interior ballistics (no predecessors that I know),
perturbation theory in celestial mechanics (predecessor: Newton).